# How to use non-contiguous nested loops

Tags: vba, excel

The below is a snippet of the code I'm using. I'm having a problem with how I need to name j. I need it to be 3,4,5,6 for the first tab_name and then 7,8,9,10 for the next and 11,12,13,14 for the one after that etc.

Can I improve the way I've attempted below?

```
tab_names = Array("11EB", "11WB", "12EB", "12WB", "13EB", "13WB", "14EB")
Location = Array(3, 7, 11)

For Each indiv_tab In tab_names
    For Each j In Location
        For i = 9 To 24
            Sheets("Front Page").Cells(2, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(i, j) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 9)
            Cells(i, j + 1) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 22)
            Cells(i, j + 2) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 35)
            Cells(i, j + 3) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 48)
        Next i
    Next j
Next
```

**EDIT**

I'm now using the below code, however, I need it go Next tab_name and Next j at the same time. Is there anyway to do this?

```
tab_names = Array("11EB", "11WB", "12EB", "12WB", "13EB", "13WB", "14EB", "14WB", "15NB", "15SB", "16NB", "16SB", "17EB", "17WB", "18EB", "18WB", "19NB", "19SB", "20NB", "20SB", "21NB", "21SB", "22NB", "22SB", "23NB", "23SB", "24NB", "24SB", "25NB", "25SB", "26NB", "26SB", "27EB", "27WB", "28EB", "28WB", "29EB", "29WB", "30EB", "30WB", "31NB", "31SB", "32NB", "32SB", "33EB", "33WB", "34EB", "34WB", "35NB", "35SB", "36NB", "36SB", "37EB", "37WB", "38NB", "38SB", "39NB", "39SB", "40EB", "40WB", "41EB", "41WB", "A12NB", "A12SB", "M11NB", "M11SB", "M25NB", "M25SB", "A120EB", "A120WB", "A120AEB", "A120AWB")
   For i = 9 To 24
    For Each indiv_tab In tab_names
     For j = 3 To 291 Step 4

            Sheets("Front Page").Cells(2, 2) = Cells(i, 1)

            Cells(i, j) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 9)
            Cells(i, j + 1) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 22)
            Cells(i, j + 2) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 35)
            Cells(i, j + 3) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 48)
      Next j
    Next
  Next i
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One improvement that stands out is that you can assign a value to every cell in a range at once, e.g. `Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(24, 1)).Value = "foo"`.  That should enable you to get rid of the inner loop over `i`.  Then if the destination columns always follow consecutively, I would get rid of the `Location` array, set `j` to 3 at the start, have a loop (with a separate counter variable) going from 1 to 4 for each sheet, and increment `j` by 4 each time round the loop.

Comment: But to answer the question in your title, `For j = 3 To 11 Step 4`.

Comment: @aucuparia Ah, thanks, that 'For j = 3 to 11 Step 4' is great. I need it to go next j and Next at the same time, how do I do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you assign a value to a range as i changes in each run - it edits a threshold from 10% to 20% to 30% etc based on a number in a drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want j to iterate through 3, 4, 5, 6 on the first tab, then 7, 8, 9, 10 on the second etc...?

If so, the below should work. Start with location as I've specified (declare as a new variable if you use it elsewhere), then manually adjust it each time.

```
tab_names = Array("11EB", "11WB", "12EB", "12WB", "13EB", "13WB", "14EB")
Location = Array(3, 4, 5, 6) '##changed this

For Each indiv_tab In tab_names
    For Each j In Location
        For i = 9 To 10
            Sheets("Front Page").Cells(2, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(i, j) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 9)
            Cells(i, j + 1) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 22)
            Cells(i, j + 2) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 35)
            Cells(i, j + 3) = Sheets(indiv_tab).Cells(2993, 48)
        Next i
    Next j

    'adjust values on each loop
    For i = 0 To UBound(Location, 1)
        Location(i) = Location(i) + 4
    Next i

Next
```